# Drawing poses in a coordinate system in rviz

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, rviz, coordinate-system

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am developing in a visual SLAM context and would like to draw the resulting camera poses for each keyframe in rviz as coordinate systems(i.e. three arrows), to see how well the localization works. Since I am inexperienced in this issue, could anyone give me an approximate description of how this can be done? Is there a tutorial or a ROS package which already does something similar? And is it necessary to use Tf for this?

Cheers,

Oier

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66510/drawing-poses-in-a-coordinate-system-in-rviz/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend to publish 3 Arrow Markers for each pose (see e.g. http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes).

You could also publish a tf frame for each pose, but that will create a lot of computational overhead in the system.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is also the "Pose" display type in rviz, which subscribes to PoseStamped messages.  The trouble for your application (I think) is that it only shows a single axis, not a sequence of them.  It would make sense to add a feature that let you specify a "history length" or number of poses to display.  Adding an issue to rviz: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/652

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1